# My model is highlighted white, how can i fix?

Tags: modeling, mesh, texturing

I downloaded a free model online and the textures appear to be there but (for lack of a better term) they seem to be highlighted white and this is not how the texture is supposed to look and the model appears to be fine in the solid viewport shading mode (minuis the weird shadows)[image] [image]

Comment: Hello and welcome! Where is the link of the model?

Comment: .. and I wonder what the lighting conditions are, in your  material preview? Which HDR? How strong?

Comment: Where can i check the lighting conditions? (im still new to blender) and im pretty sure the model didnt have an HDR applied.